# Control the timeout for locking Exclusive SQLite3 database

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, locking

I have a SQLite database that I want to lock for synchronization purposes. I don't want a process that runs async on a different box processing data that has been added from a different box until it has finished with updates. DataAccess is a class that connects to sPackageFileName and reuses the same connection as long as sPackageFileName is the same or unless .Close method is called. So basically DataAccess.ExecCommand executes a command.
 In Google I found this ....

```
DataAccess.ExecCommand("PRAGMA locking_mode = EXCLUSIVE", sPackageFileName)
DataAccess.ExecCommand("BEGIN EXCLUSIVE", sPackageFileName)
DataAccess.ExecCommand("COMMIT", sPackageFileName)
```

This works as advertise. If I run this on box A and then on box B I get a "database locked" exception. The problem is how long it takes. I found a PRAGMA busy_timeout. This PRAGMA is timeout controls access locks, not database locks. I am stratring to think there is not PRAGMA for database lock timeout. Right now it seems about 3-4 minutes. One other note, the sPackageFileName is not on either box, they (box A and B) connect to it over a share drive.
Also I am using the VB.NET wrapper for the SQLite dll.

Comment: There is no such thing as an "access lock"; SQLite has only a database lock.

Comment: Sorry for my bad terminology. Seems like in my research SQLite uses page locking for it's internal synchronization. Could be record, but doesn't matter for this question. Then there was a lock when a Begin transaction is executed. Then the pragma locking mode.The Begin transaction default timeout is 5 seconds. I found a pragma that can change that one, but the timeout I am experiencing for locking mode is more like 3-4 minutes. That the one I want change.

Comment: There is no page or record lock; SQLite [always uses a database lock](http://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html).

Comment: Is there any way to change the time_out?

Comment: With PRAGMA busy_timeout. That 3-4 minutes wait is not from the database.

Comment: Ok, so my command "PRAGMA busy_timeout = 1000" should set it for 1 sec. So what I am hearing is there is something outside of SQLite timing out. Could it be the "System.Data.Sqlite" provider? Let me update my post and I will include my connect string. Sounds like I am barking up the wrong tree. :-)

Comment: What specific operation blocks?

Answer (score 0):

CL got me on the right trail. It was the timeout of the .NET command. Here the code setting it up from my class.

```
   Dim con As DbConnection = OpenDb(DatabaseName, StoreNumber, ShareExclusive, ExtType)
   Dim cmd As DbCommand = con.CreateCommand()
   If _QueryTimeOut > -1 Then cmd.CommandTimeout = _QueryTimeOut
```

Don't get hang up on the variables, the purpose of posting the code is show I could show the property I was talking about. The default _QueryTimeOut was set the 300 (seconds). I set cmd.ComandTimeout to 1 (second) and it returned as expected.

As CL finally got through to me, the timeout was happening someplace else. Sometimes it takes a kick to get you out of the box. :-)